# php echoing images based on $answer

Tags: php

This is a university project and I have a page will a php calculator where users enter '$valuea' which is likely to be between 0-550 then they will hit submit which subtracts '$valueb' which is 250, giving them '$answer'.

What I need help with is I was to have a particular image echo out once the user hit submit, which depends on the figure of $answer.

Here's what I have so far but it is not working;

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = '250';
$answer = $valuea - $valueb;

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='calculator.php'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Work out how much you could be     saving</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>How much do you spend a year?</td><td align="center"><input     type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Minus the average price of an n-power student tarrif* Leave     Blank:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>You could be saving:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if($db_server){

$image1 = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename='image1');"

$image2 = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename='image2');"

$image3 = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename='image3');"

$image4 = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename='image4');"

$image5 = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename='image5');"

if( $answer > 0 and $answer < 150 )?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image1;?>"/>

else if( $answer < 250)
   <img src="<?php  echo $image2;?>"/>
else if( $answer < 350)
   <img src="<?php  echo $image3;?>"/>
else if( $answer < 450)
   <img src="<?php  echo $image4;?>"/>
else if( $answer < 550)
   <img src="<?php  echo $image5;?>"/>
   <?php
else
   echo 'error';

}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$db_server`?

Comment: where you get query result try to echo $image things? try echo with <img src="your url">

Comment: Should we fix your syntax errors? or is this pseudo code?

Comment: `<img>` is self-closing. Therefore `<img .../>`, not `<img ..></img>`

Comment: I'm getting an error message on the mysqli_query query lines and also on the last "else" line?

Comment: Nicely done "Storyboard" layout; now it's time to loop through. You can't expect to just put variables and make it magically pop out like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how? Sorry I'm in first year at university, I'm not code savvy

Comment: Have you not read any tutorials on querying a database? I don't mean to sound "mean", but Lordie, querying a database is what SQL is all about. There's just too much work to put in an "answer".

Comment: You designed a "pseudo" piece of code. You're not fetching or using any of MySQL's `mysqli_fetch_row` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` etc. and expect us to finish it? Sorry, I don't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a real mess. I've cleaned it a bit.

```
<?php
$valuea = (isset($_POST['valuea']) && is_numeric($_POST['valuea'])) ? $_POST['valuea'] : 0;
$valueb = 250;

$answer = $valuea - $valueb;

?>
<form method='post' action='calculator.php'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
    <tr class="calcheading">
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Work out how much you could be     saving</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>How much do you spend a year?</td>
        <td align="center"><input     type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>Minus the average price of an n-power student tarrif* Leave     Blank:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="submit">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td><i>You could be saving:</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if($db_server){

    switch( $answer ){
        case $answer > 0 and $answer < 150 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image1'");
        break;

        case $answer < 250 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image2'");
        break;

        case $answer < 350 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image3'");
        break;

        case $answer < 450 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image4'");
        break;

        case $answer < 550 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image5'");
        break;
    }

    echo "<img src='$image' alt='' />";

}
?>
```

Comment: Now, how is this supposed to work; curious. There's nothing to the effect of `fetching` anything.

Comment: What do you mean? He had a lot of syntax erros(I've fixed them, but it's still untested code).

Comment: There's nothing to the effect of `mysqli_fetch_row` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` etc. I take it the OP knows enough to fill in the blanks then. (Yet I kind of doubt that). If the OP accepts it "as is", I will +1

Comment: I tested which has the answer as 250 and got the error "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/cs12jcw/public_html/n-power/includes/calculator.php on line 87" with line 87 being"case $answer < 350 : $image = mysqli_query("SELECT URL FROM images WHERE imagename = 'image3'");
        break;"

Comment: I've just took a quick look at `mysqli_query`(http://nl3.php.net/mysqli_query) and saw that you need to use `$db_server->query`(In assumption that `$db_server` is your database connection). And, ofcourse, you need to fetch your results to get the link like @Fred-ii- mentioned.